# Search/Extract value from 1D JSON Array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

Assuming i have a JSON String stored as a `json` data-type like so: `[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,512,1024]`

How will i be able to extract or search for the value of `4` or `8`?

clearly, i cannot make use of the `LIKE` keyword since if i am to use this versus `4` with query `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... LIKE '%4%'`, i might be able to pull `64` and `1024`. Same with the value of `8` being able to pull `128`.

Is there any equivalent JSON Function similar to `JSON_CONTAINS(...)` being used for JSON Objects / Key-Value Pairs.

This part, i am seriously struggling to cope with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just scoured the MySQL JSON function documentation, and I did not see anything which seemed to do a JSON array contains operation.  But there is a way to proceed here using base string functions.  You may search for a target number, surrounded on both sides by commas.  To make this work, we need to replace the opening and closing brackets with commas.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN REPLACE(REPLACE(json, '[', ','), ']', ',') LIKE '%,4,%'
         THEN '4 present' ELSE '4 not present' END AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

The demo below shows that the query covers the edge cases as well.

### Demo

Comment: while there really is no JSON Function for such a thing - as also checked by you, you have managed to make a work around for this limitation. Thanks @Tim